# Need a better way to Update lots of data from an excel to a Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have almost 400 records in an excel sheet that i need to insert in a single table using sql statement.Now it is really hectic if i need to manually write the update statements for all those data one by one. Is there any efficient way so that i can update all data into that table by using some kind of script or anything else. It would be a great help as it can save a lot of time for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think You are looking for [Sql Loader](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aLoader_FAQ).

Answer (score 2):

You could simply export your Excel spreadsheet as a CSV file, and then use an [external table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/et_concepts.htm) in Oracle to access the data.

```
CREATE TABLE external_table (
  id varchar2(10),
  col varchar2(20),
  ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
     TYPE ORACLE_LOADER DEFAULT DIRECTORY ext_tab_dir
     ACCESS PARAMETERS (FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',')
     LOCATION ('mydata.csv'))
```

Then you can just update your table with the data from your Excel spreadsheet

```
merge into my_table t1
using external_table t2
   on ( t2.id = t1.id )
 when matched then
    update set t1.col = t2.col
 when not matched then
     insert (id, col) values(t2.id, t2.col)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If you have any chance of using `PLSQL` Developer ,you can load the data in to your database by TEXT Importer and `ODBC Importer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the cell values to build insert statements with excel's native concatenation operators, then copy/paste those values.